# set 2 while loop with CSV files in Jmeter

Tags: csv, while-loop, jmeter

I want to add 2 while loop in my Jmeter project with 2 CSV DataSet Config items like this:

```
While Loop condition: ${__javaScript("${var1}"!="<EOF>")}
    CSVDataSetConfig variables: var1 - recycle : false, stop thread on current thread: true
    While Loop condition: ${__javaScript("${var2}"!="<EOF>")}
        CSVDataSetConfig variables: var2 - recycle : false, stop thread on current thread: false
        HTTP Request
        . . .
```

This must execute the second loop until the first loop's variable (var1) is at the end of the file.

But here's the issue, var2 is stuck on < EOF>, so the second while loop is skipped.

Do you have a solution to set var2 to the begining of the file, or another solution?